# Differential equation, symmetric about 0?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Solving the following numerically (with different values of $u(-1)$)

$(2-\cos(\pi x))u''(t) + u(t) = 1$ and $u(-1) = u(1)$

the solutions seem to be symmetric about $0$. Is it true in general (ie no matter which value $u(-1)$ takes)? Please give me some hints, thanks.

Eg for $u(-1) = u(1) = -5$, Mathematica gives

[image]

For $u(-1) = u(1) = 1.5$,

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are. Note that if $u$ solves the differential equation $$v(t)u''(t)+w(t)u'(t)+x(t)u(t)=y(t),
$$ 
where the functions $v$, $x$ and $y$ are even and $w$ is odd, then the function $$\bar u:t\mapsto u(-t),$$ solves it as well. Adding symmetric conditions such as $u(c)=u(-c)$ for some $c\ne0$ ensures that $\bar u=u$ as soon as the solution is unique, that is, that $u$ is even.